# Solving the differential equation $m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=Ae^{-\gamma t}\sin(\omega t).$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

A particle of mass $m$ moving along the $x$-axis, is acted upon by a force:
$$F\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}A\mathrm{e}^{-\gamma t}\sin\left(\omega t\right),&t\ge0;\\0,&t<0.\end{cases}$$
Initial conditions are: $x(0)=x_{0},\dot{x}(0)=\dot{x}_{0}.$ Here $\dot{x}$ is $\frac{dx}{dt}$.
Find the equation of motion $x(t)$ for the particle.

**My attempt:**

In both cases we want to solve the differential equation $m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=F(t)$. For the second case, the equation becomes trivial $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=0$ with the solution $x(t)=\dot{x}_{0}t+x_0$. However, I am having trouble solving the differential equation
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=Ae^{-\gamma t}\sin(\omega t).$$
My approach was just integrating both sides, but I am stuck in the seemingly never ending integration by parts loop. Could someone show how to solve this for $x(t)$?

Comment: Just an idea: Try using m*dv/dt instead, solve for v(t), then use it to get x(t)

Comment: I think getting v(t) should be easy enough: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=exp%5C%2840%29-x%5C%2841%29*sin%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29+integral)

Comment: And you would get x(t) from there.

Comment: I get $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{Ae^{-\gamma t}(\gamma \sin (t \omega)+\omega \cos(t \omega))}{m(\gamma^2 + \omega^2)}+C$ (if it's correct?). How do I integrate then to get $x(t)$?

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%28%28A+%28%CF%89+Cos%5Bt+%CF%89%5D+%2B+%CE%B3+Sin%5Bt+%CF%89%5D%29%29%2F%28E%5E%28t+%CE%B3%29+m+%28%CE%B3%5E2+%2B+%CF%89%5E2%29%29%29+integrate+with+respect+to+t) you go. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Perhaps you can use that $$\sin\omega t = \frac{e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t}}{2i}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could try Laplace transform of your differential equation:
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[m x''(t)=A \exp (-\gamma  t) \sin (\omega t)\right](s)$$

Results in s-domain equation
$$m \left(s^2 X(s)-s x(0)-x'(0)\right)=\frac{A \omega }{(s+\gamma )^2+\omega ^2}$$

Then $$X(s)=\frac{A \omega }{m s^2 \left((s+\gamma)^2+\omega ^2\right)}+\frac{x(0)}{s}+\frac{x'(0)}{s^2}$$

Now we go back to time domain with inverse Laplace transform:

With $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{x(0)}{s}\right](t)=x(0)=x_0$ and $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{x'(0)}{s^2}\right](t)=t x'(0)=t \dot{x}_0$

we finally get

$$x(t)=\frac{A \omega}{m}  \left(-\frac{2 \gamma }{\left(\gamma ^2+\omega ^2\right)^2}+\frac{t}{\gamma ^2+\omega ^2}+\frac{e^{-\gamma t} \left(\left(\gamma ^2-\omega ^2\right) \sin (\omega t)+2 \gamma  \omega  \cos (\omega t)\right)}{\omega  \left(\gamma ^2+\omega ^2\right)^2}\right)+x_0+t\dot{x}_0$$